# Xcode-organizer does not show app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, info.plist

I developed app for iPhone, now i want to submit it to the store.

when i click on organizer - Archives, it shows me only one thing called `QRUI` and it doesn't show my app..

[image]
Now, how should i validate and distribute my app ?

***Please help, i am new to iOS..***

Comment: restart your system and try again

Comment: already tried, but didn't successes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

its a organization `archive` category.First you Create a archive like bellow step:-

select Device in xcode running project option:-
[image]

After it you goto product-->

[image]

wait processing of xcode

[image]

After it finished check your organization organization `archives`

Answer (score 3):

The issue occurs when you use a third party project or library in your project.

Go to the Build Settings of the third party library/project targets and set Skip Install flag YES.

Answer (score 1):

The issue occurs when you use a third party project or library in your project.

If that is the case.

Go to the **Build Settings** of the third party library/project's **targets** and set **Skip Install** flag to **YES**.

[image: Skip Install Flag]

Answer (score 0):

There is a technical note you can read about it which solved my problem, see here: [enter link description here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2215/_index.html)